# Regular expression to extract inner text

Tags: regex, r

I got thousands of messages with the following structures

```
Some header text
-------------------------------------------
text I want to extract
-------------------------------------------
Some footer text
```

or

```
text I want to extract
```

or

```
-------------------------------------------
Some header text
-------------------------------------------
text I want to extract
-------------------------------------------
Some footer text
-------------------------------------------
```

from which I want to extract the `"text I want to extract"` part and discard anything else. 
Now I am able to do this in several lines of R code such as

```
str_locate(messages[i],"-{5,}")
```

But that amounts to a lot of code. Is there a way to extract the text in a one-liner?

Comment: I have edited the original text and included some structural variations.

Comment: The structural variations are meaningless unless you define the text separately. What you really are doing is `delimiter to delimiter`, that's all you can do so far. That would be something like `^-{5,}\n((?:.*\n)*?)^-{5,}` in multi line mode (if supported), `\n-{5,}\n((?:[^\n]*\n)*?)-{5,}` if not.

Comment: Thanks sln - tried it here:

http://www.regexr.com/

and it worked for the 1st and 3rd structural variation, but not for the 2nd.

Comment: Well, like I said there is no structure until you define it. So far,  `text I want to extract` is English jibberish to a regex engine  which does not parse language.

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like this with `strsplit()`

```
x <- c("Some header text
-------------------------------------------
text I want to extract
-------------------------------------------
Some footer text", "text I want to extract",
"-------------------------------------------
Some header text
-------------------------------------------
text I want to extract
-------------------------------------------
Some footer text
-------------------------------------------")

sapply(
    strsplit(x, "\n?-+\n?"),
    function(x) if(length(x) == 1) x else x[nzchar(x)][2]
)
# [1] "text I want to extract" "text I want to extract"
# [3] "text I want to extract"
```

Technically that's a one-liner :-)

Comment: Thanks Richard - that's much more concise than anything I have come up with so far!

Comment: No problem.  It seems ultra-difficult to regex that correctly so I figured it would be easier and safer to split on the `---` and line breaks and grab the middle entry (or lone entry)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a single `gsub` command for this task.

```
gsub("^(?:[^\n]*\n){1,2}(?:-+\n)?|(?:\n[^\n]*){2,3}$", "", vec)
# [1] "text I want to extract" "text I want to extract" "text I want to extract"
```

where `vec` is this vector:

```
vec <- c("Some header text
-------------------------------------------
text I want to extract
-------------------------------------------
Some footer text", 
"text I want to extract",
"-------------------------------------------
Some header text
-------------------------------------------
text I want to extract
-------------------------------------------
Some footer text
-------------------------------------------")
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Richard Scriven's data,

```
 sub('\n.*', '', sub('^-*\n[A-Za-z ]+\n-+\n|^[A-Za-z ]+\n-*\n', '', x))
 #[1] "text I want to extract" "text I want to extract" 
 #  "text I want to extract"
```